# mkdir in OS X does not create the full directory tree

Tags: c++, linux, macos, directory

I am trying to use the mkdir API in OS X (and would like to use it in linux) with C++ to create a directory path.

Say I want to create a directory like: "/Users/luca/Subject/Data". "/Users/luca" structure already exists. So, I do something like:

```
struct stat st = {0};
if (stat(path, &st) == -1) {
    return mkdir(path, S_IRWXU);
}
```

This always returns -1. If I try ""/Users/luca/Subject", it works fine.

Does anyone know how I can get the mkdir -p like behaviour without invoking the system() process call.

Comment: `mkdir()` is [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mkdir.2.html) to fail (`ENOENT`) if a component of the path prefix doesn't exist. You have to iterate up the directories until you find one that exists and then create each subdirectory as you unwind back to the original path. A recursive function is a natural fit.